# How to install Mysql 5.6 on RHEL8 from Mysql repos?

Tags: mysql, dnf, rhel8

I'm new to dnf, so this is probably obvious to someone.

I did check versionlock and checked for any exclude lines in any of the /etc/yum.repos.d files. But, when I have any other repos enabled, I cannot find mysql server to install. I can try to install it with all other repos disabled, but then it cannot find all the dependencies.

```
[root@ip-10-9-10-242 yum.repos.d]# dnf clean all
42 files removed
[root@ip-10-9-10-242 yum.repos.d]# dnf --disablerepo "*"  --enablerepo "mysql56-community" list available
Last metadata expiration check: 0:07:40 ago on Tue 30 Jul 2019 12:38:45 UTC.
Available Packages
mysql-community-bench.x86_64                                                                                        5.6.45-2.el7                                                                          mysql56-community
...
mysql-community-server.x86_64                                                                                       5.6.45-2.el7                                                                          mysql56-community
mysql-community-test.x86_64                                                                                         5.6.45-2.el7                                                                          mysql56-community
[root@ip-10-9-10-242 yum.repos.d]# dnf --enablerepo "mysql56-community" search mysql-community-server.x86_64
Last metadata expiration check: 0:07:59 ago on Tue 30 Jul 2019 12:38:48 UTC.
No matches found.
[root@ip-10-9-10-242 yum.repos.d]# dnf search mysql-community
Last metadata expiration check: 0:10:57 ago on Tue 30 Jul 2019 12:38:48 UTC.
============================================================================================== Name Matched: mysql-community ==============================================================================================
mysql-community-bench.x86_64 : MySQL benchmark suite
mysql-community-release.noarch : MySQL repository configuration for yum
mysql-community-release.noarch : MySQL repository configuration for yum
mysql-community-embedded.i686 : MySQL embedded library
mysql-community-embedded.x86_64 : MySQL embedded library
mysql-community-embedded-devel.i686 : Development header files and libraries for MySQL as an embeddable library
mysql-community-embedded-devel.x86_64 : Development header files and libraries for MySQL as an embeddable library
```

So, you can see some of the stuff in mysql56 repo is found (like bench) but the server isn't.
I'd also previously done :

```
yum-config-manager --disable mysql80-community
yum-config-manager --enable mysql56-community
```

And can see :

```
[root@ip-10-9-10-242 yum.repos.d]# dnf repolist
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:04 ago on Tue 30 Jul 2019 13:03:47 UTC.
repo id                         repo name                                status
mysql-connectors-community      MySQL Connectors Community                 118
mysql-tools-community           MySQL Tools Community                       95
mysql56-community               MySQL 5.6 Community Server                 169
rhui-client-config-server-8     Red Hat Update Infrastructure 3 Client C     3
rhui-rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 -  5,472
rhui-rhel-8-baseos-rhui-rpms    Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 -  2,029
```

For anyone still confused, what can't be found, can't be installed.

```
[root@ip-10-9-10-242 ~]# dnf install mysql-community-server
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:12 ago on Thu 01 Aug 2019 09:14:02 UTC.
No match for argument: mysql-community-server
Error: Unable to find a match
```

OK, so a bit of "-v" action and it says the packages are excluded. BUT I can disable all excludes and it still says they're excluded.

```
[root@ip-10-9-10-242 dnf]# dnf repoquery --repo mysql56-community --available mysql-community-server-0:5.6.45-2.el7.x86_64
Last metadata expiration check: 0:13:17 ago on Thu 01 Aug 2019 17:12:25 UTC.
mysql-community-server-0:5.6.45-2.el7.x86_64


[root@ip-10-9-10-242 dnf]# dnf --enablerepo=mysql56-community  --disableexcludepkgs all --disableexcludes all  install mysql-community-bench
Last metadata expiration check: 0:14:46 ago on Thu 01 Aug 2019 17:13:30 UTC.
Error: 
 Problem: package mysql-community-bench-5.6.45-2.el7.x86_64 requires mysql-community-server(x86-64) >= 5.6.10, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best candidate for the job
  - package mysql-community-server-5.6.15-4.el7.x86_64 is excluded
  - package mysql-community-server-5.6.16-1.el7.x86_64 is excluded
.....
  - package mysql-community-server-5.6.44-2.el7.x86_64 is excluded
  - package mysql-community-server-5.6.45-2.el7.x86_64 is excluded


  [root@ip-10-9-10-242 dnf]# dnf --disablerepo "*" --enablerepo=mysql56-community  --disableexcludepkgs all --disableexcludes all  install mysql-community-bench
  Last metadata expiration check: 0:18:12 ago on Thu 01 Aug 2019 17:12:25 UTC.
  Error: 
   Problem: cannot install the best candidate for the job
    - nothing provides /usr/bin/perl needed by mysql-community-bench-5.6.45-2.el7.x86_64
    - nothing provides perl(Getopt::Long) needed by mysql-community-bench-5.6.45-2.el7.x86_64
    - nothing provides perl(Data::Dumper) needed by mysql-community-bench-5.6.45-2.el7.x86_64
    - nothing provides perl(POSIX) needed by mysql-community-bench-5.6.45-2.el7.x86_64
    - nothing provides perl(Cwd) needed by mysql-community-bench-5.6.45-2.el7.x86_64
    - nothing provides perl(DBI) needed by mysql-community-bench-5.6.45-2.el7.x86_64
    - nothing provides perl(Benchmark) needed by mysql-community-bench-5.6.45-2.el7.x86_64
    - nothing provides perl(sigtrap) needed by mysql-community-bench-5.6.45-2.el7.x86_64
  (try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Comment: What I used to do on RHEL 7 :

rpm -i https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch.rpm;
yum-config-manager --disable mysql80-community;
yum-config-manager --enable mysql56-community;
yum search mysql-community-server;
yum -y install mysql-community-server

Answer (score 0):

For those who will come here searching for the solution, here's the way to install MySQL community packages on RHEL8: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-repo-excerpt/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html. The official page. And the culprit is default mysql module. Disable it and dnf will find community packages no problem.